# How to show Google Maps tile overlays of Google Earth's Old-world maps (or a blank / physical world map)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geography

I am trying to build a Google Maps-driven web application that can display a map of the whole world in one or all of the following configurations:

- A continent-outline map, only differentiating between land and water (like [this](http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=-0.703107,-1.40625&spn=151.859736,305.859375&z=2), but without the country borders/names, and without showing any additional detail as you zoom in)
- A physical geography map of the world, containing absolutely no road, city, or political borders (so the default satellite map is out - if I can't get anything else working, I'm considering just restricting the zoom-level such that you can't get in close enough to see modern features)
- The same kind of old-world maps shown [here](http://www.gearthhacks.com/dlfile4943/Old-Map-of-the-World.htm) and [here](http://www.gearthhacks.com/dlfile4729/Kirchers-world.htm) for Google Earth.

A similar effect to what I'm after can be achieved with the old maps from the Rumsey Collection ([q.v.](http://rumsey.geogarage.com/maps/CassiniWorldGlobe1790.html)), which are excellent but rather bandwidth-intensive and slow down the GMaps performance significantly.  Simpler, less detailed images would better suit my purposes.

Is there an efficient way to load those world-spanning KMZ graphical files from bullet 3 as tilesets?

How about the physical or silhouette-based map? If necessary, one could follow the GMaps guideline for carving out .png files to represent each tile if there exists a freely available starting map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use open-source MapTiler application - http://www.maptiler.org/ or the command line utility gdal2tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on building custom tiled maps:
http://webtide.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/custom-google-maps/

This appears to be a service for creating custom tiled maps:
http://www.maplib.net/

Good luck!

Comment: The maplib site appears to be temporarily down, but the wordpress one is exceedingly helpful.  Thanks!